# Postgres trigger that affects rows with certain values

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

I'm postgres newbie and i have a question regarding triggers. Lets say we have 2 tables. One with cities and one with people.

CITIES:

[image]

PEOPLE:

[image]

I need a trigger that updates 'processed' value in table cities from 0 to 1 when 'processed' value in table people updates from 0 to 1 for all people from that city.

For example: John, Ian and Claire are from Berlin and when 'processed' value is updated to 1 for each of them, then the trigger updates processed value for Berlin in table cities to 1.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: This seems to be the wrong way to structure the data.  Just use a `join` to look to see whether the city has been processed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION mytrigger() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $mytrigger$
    BEGIN
        IF (SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM PEOPLE WHERE city_id = NEW.city_id AND processed = '0')) THEN
            UPDATE CITIES SET processed = '0' WHERE id = NEW.city_id;
            RETURN NEW;
        ELSE
            UPDATE CITIES SET processed = '1' WHERE id = NEW.city_id;
            RETURN NEW;
        END IF;
    END;
$mytrigger$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER mytrigger
AFTER UPDATE ON PEOPLE
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE mytrigger();
```

Answer (score 1):

try this query:

```
with c as (
    select city_id
    from people
    where name = NEW.name
)
, a as (
select avg(processed) 
from people
join c on c.city_id = people.city_id
)
update cities u
set processed = 1
from a
where u.id = a.city_id
and avg = 1
```

alias c gets city id, then a aggregates processed for that sict id in people and lastly update updates only when all names are processed.